# Redirect docker logs to file

Tags: docker, io-redirection

Normally when I redirect my docker log to a text file, all the content will store in the output file.

This is what I expected outcome

```
[root@ip-xx-xx-xx-xx ~]$ docker logs aa46e7139ce5 > docker.log
[root@ip-xx-xx-xx-xx ~]$
```

But sometimes the output will become following and the errors are not included in the docker.log

```
[root@ip-xx-xx-xx-xx ~]$ docker logs aaasdas9c356 > docker.log
Debugger failed to attach: handshake failed - received >GET / HTTP/1.0 < - expected >JDWP-Handshake<
Debugger failed to attach: recv failed during handshake: Resource temporarily unavailable
Debugger failed to attach: received >< - expected >JDWP-Handshake<
[root@ip-xx-xx-xx-xx ~]$
```

Just wondering why the output will have different behaviour.

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're missing stderr. The output redirect handles file descriptor 1, stdout. For messages sent to stderr on file descriptor 2, you need to redirect that separately. Either to the same location:

```
docker logs aaasdas9c356 > docker.log 2>&1
```

Or to a separate file:

```
docker logs aaasdas9c356 > docker.log 2>docker.err
```